# Deleting InProgress Registry key from windows registry

Tags: facebook, registry

I am using Adobe flash professional cs6 for developing facebook Apps while installing the Adobe Flash professional cs6 It can't installing throwing System Error,When googling I found that the solution to the problem is to delete the InProgress registry key But I don't found any InProgress Registry key In Windows 7 Registry to delete please let me know how to delete the In Progress registry key

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be if you've used one of those free "registry cleaners" on your PC. You might still be able to download from IE if this is the case.